# Prometheus - getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: mysql, percona, grafana, prometheus

In the targets page of Prometheus, I'm getting the following error:

[image: Error]

I'm using it in Linux host

Prometheus Version:

```
prometheus, version 1.1.2 (branch: master, revision: 36fbdcc30fd13ad796381dc934742c559feeb1b5)
  build user:       root@a74d279a0d22
  build date:       20160908-13:12:43
  go version:       go1.6.3
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

As the scrape error message says, Prometheus can't open a connection to your target at `172.19.36.189:9104`. Can you connect to that IP/port manually? Are you perhaps running Prometheus in a container where it cannot reach that IP?

Comment: how to connect directly? I have one linux host and I have MySQL running in that. I have prometheus and grafana running in the same host. Connection is local only. Manual how? Do help Julius!

Comment: Julius can you help me out here?

Comment: @tesla747: Try wget or a browser: the endpoint also exposes an html page.

Comment: Yeah, try reaching http://172.19.36.189:9104/metrics in your browser. The problem is that Prometheus cannot open a TCP connection to that IP and port combination. That can either be because there really is nothing listening on that IP and port or because you have some setup in which a connection is prevented (running Prometheus in a container without network access to that IP, or running into other networking/firewall issues). At that point, it's not really a Prometheus-related question anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The connection may be failing anywhere in the traffic flow. This can help identify:
[image]

That said, if your service is running in the same host as Prometheus, you should try and use 127.0.0.1:9104/metrics as the endpoint in Prometheus scrape config, ensuring the service is indeed listening in port 9104.

As you try to troubleshoot and fix issues in each layer, check connectivity from your Prometheus host using a simple:

```
nc -v <service-ip> <service-port>
```

Comment: I know it is an old question. Answered it to help anybody thats looking for similar problem.

Comment: Does it make a difference to use `127.0.0.1:9104` instead of `localhost:9104`?

Answer (score -1):

Three things to check here:

1. Networking:

Is the scrape target `http://172.19.36.189:9104/metrics` reachable from where you've opened the Prometheus GUI in the browser? Check `curl -vvv http://172.19.36.189:9104/metrics` and any proxy to `http://172.19.36.189:9104/metrics`.

2. Prometheus logs:

Start prometheus with debugging turned on by using the flag --log.level:

```
$ /bin/prometheus -h
...
--log.level=info      [debug,
                      info,
                      warn,
                      error]
```

Then, check the container's logs using:

```
docker logs <name of prometheus container>
kubectl logs <name of prometheus pod>
```

3. Is the scrape target's port `9104` exposed in the container/pod/service?